# how can i use ternary operator in express-handelbars to assign value in my input feild?

Tags: ternary-operator, express-handlebars

I want something like this-

```
<input type="text" id="agentsignupname" name="agentsignupname" 
class="form-control" value={{typeof name!="undefined"?name:" "}}>
```

This peice of code is not working as it shows-

> Parse error on line 14:
>   ...rol" value={{typeof name!="undefined"?na
>   -----------------------^
>   Expecting 'CLOSE_RAW_BLOCK', 'CLOSE', 'CLOSE_UNESCAPED', 'OPEN_SEXPR', 'CLOSE_SEXPR', 'ID', 'OPEN_BLOCK_PARAMS', 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'BOOLEAN', 'UNDEFINED', 'NULL', 'DATA', 'SEP', got 'INVALID'

Answer (score 0):

Use Helpers in your app.js add

```
const exhbs = require('express-handlebars')

var hbs= exhbs.create({
helpers:{
    name: ()=>typeof name!="undefined"?name:" " 
}
```

and then in your template add

```
<input type="text" id="agentsignupname" name="agentsignupname" 
class="form-control" value={{name}}""/>
```